# trying to cast a NSSsearchfiled in swift xcode

Tags: swift, cocoa

i'm trying to call a function thats in another class

but its telling me im missing a parameter

this code is on my class1

```
 @IBAction func nssearchfiled(_ sender: Any) {

    class2().functionforsearchfield()
}
```

its saying
Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

update:

heres the code in my class number 2

```
import Cocoa

class class2{



func functionforsearchfield() {

   print("works")

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code (or at least declaration) of functionforsearchfield? Also it is not clear, is class2 - a variable or you instantiate class2 before calling that function?

Comment: You need to post your code for class2, but what you have written is almost certainly wrong: you are creating an instance, then running a method on it, without suing any kind of return value and then letting the instance die immediately after.  this doesn't pass the smell test of good coding practice.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i updated my post and added my class2 code

Comment: This code, copied to the Playground, works fine.

Comment: jeepson, those are two classes not once classes

Comment: Jess-on I tell ya its. 2 class can't u see it?

Answer (score -1):

alright I figured out how, heres how I done it

class1

```
@IBAction func nssearchfiled(_ sender: Any) {
    class2().functionforsearchfield((nssearchfiled)!)
}
```

class2

class EnterPressedInRoomBarxxx{

```
func functionforsearchfield(_ nsearchfildpassed: NSSearchField) {
     let newdata = nsearchfildpassed as NSSearchField
 }

}
```

Comment: In your question you show `func functionforsearchfield()` and we see that it clearly takes *no parameters*. This is why the error message didn't match and your question could not be answered. And then in your answer you tell us that the solution was to add a parameter when calling it, and that this parameter is itself another method. This is nonsense because it answers for code that is different from the one in the question. 100% useless.

Comment: moritz what i asked was realy easy to understand